# Multicolumn table

Tags: tables

I want to make a the following table.

```
student   roll no.       lab report
-----------------------------------
                       1   2   3   4
```

how do I make it.
I used multicolumn bt that give lab report at a level above "student" n 
"roll no." like

```
                         lab report
student  roll no.      1   2    3    4
```

but I dont want that
I want all student, roll no. & lab report on same level.

[image: this is what i get]

but i want lab report to be in the same row as student, roll no.,presnt, perform & total and want 1(3), 2(3), 3(3), Assign(5) & lab t to b in the next row (in column of lab report).

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \scalebox{0.68} {
        \rowcolors{1}{cyan}{lightgray}
        \begin{tabular}{|m{2cm}|m{2.5cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1.5cm}|m{1.5cm}|m{2.5cm}|m{2.5cm}|m{2cm}|}
            \hline
            &&\multicolumn{5}{| c }{Lab Report}&&&&\\
            \hline
            Student & Roll No.& 1(3) & 2(3) & 3(3) & Assign(5) & Lab T(15)& Present(15) & Perform(20) & Total(50) 
        \end{tabular}
    }           
    \caption{Lab Result }
    \label{result}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a MWE of what you've tried so far.

Comment: Please clarify. Your request is somewhat unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Since your request was quite convoluted and unclear, I apologise if I missed the crux of it. I tried my best.

From my understanding this should suffice:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c c|c c c c|c|c c|}
\cline{1-7}
Student & Roll No. & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Lab Report} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & 1(3) & 2(3) & 3(3) & Assign(5) Lab T(15) & Present(15) & Perform(20) & Total(50) \\ \cline{3-9}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, "Student roll no." should be on the first row.

Comment: Well, I knew I messed something up. Thank you for your correction. Be assured that I will edit my answer ASAP.